# How to set the image URL when loading images in a loop in Vite

Tags: vuejs3, vite, server-side-rendering

I need to display `data` attribute in DOM, `1.png` can be displayed normally, but `2.png` cannot. I can't use `new URL()` because I need `SSR`, what methods can I use. I need help.

```js
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
const data = ref([
  { title: "One", imgSrc: new URL('../assets/image/1.png',import.meta.url).href },
  { title: "Two", imgSrc: await import("@/assets/image/2.png").default },
]);
</script>

<template>
  <div v-for="({ title, imgSrc }, index) in data">
    <p>{{ title }}</p>
    <img :src="imgSrc" alt="" />
  </div>
</template>
```